# Cache video background

Tags: performance, css, caching, browser-cache

I have a background video that plays on my site this is working well but I noticed the browser is always downloading the video as it loops and if the wifi disconnects the video stops playing. I have googled cacheing background videos but have had not luck finding relevant answers or forms. Does anyone know how to do this or what the terms might be to find information on this?

I am also curious what would be better for performance. To continue to ask for the video content from the server or to make the user cache it.

As a side note this site https://rentmoola.com/ does what I want. It is able to keep playing the video even if the wifi turns off.

Comment: What has HTML5 `video` to do with CSS3?

Comment: Any way, even if using `manifest` you'll not have support for IE. So caching data for offline mode? YES. IE? no... at least not for IE<10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at Rentmoola and I can tell you the video is not cached, a call is made to the server each time the video loops, and the video should stop playing if the Wifi is disconnected.  Videos probably should not be stored in your cache because of their size.

Comment: haha thanks Gabby I was going to ask you. Im going to scrap the idea of casheing, its not an offline app and I cant find anything that suggests its a big performance hit. Weird though. It seems to be playing on my computer when I disconnect.